# Form not submitting after ajax partial render

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a site, that allows you to make wishes. I want the user to be able to create a wish from anywhere on the site, which is why I thought of going with an jquery/ajax approach.

I have a link on the top-bar which enables a modal:

_header.html.erb (the modal-part)

```
<div id="make_wish" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="make_wish" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="make_wish">Make a wish</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="linkpreview">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <label for="url">Retrieve item</label>
          <input id="url" type="text" placeholder="http://">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <%= link_to "Get info", new_item_path, id: "urlb", class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After clicking the "Get info" button, new.js.erb is called:

```
    $("#linkpreview").hide().after('<%= j render("item_fields") %>');
```

This renders: _item_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(@item, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit "Wish", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Now, when I fill out the form, and hit the submit-button, nothing happens.

I'm new to both rails, jquery and ajax, and any help is thus much appreciated!

** Edit **

items_controller.rb

```
def new
    if signed_in?
        @item = Item.new
        @user = current_user
    else
        render 'users/new'
    end
end

def create
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = Item.create!(params[:item])
    @item.wishes.build(list_id: @list.id)
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "Item created!"
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: You should look into form_tag with :remote=>true option (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

Comment: I have tried this `<%= form_for(@item, remote: true, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>` with no luck

Comment: You may want to check what is doing your server by checking your console while you submit the form.

Comment: You can check your console when you click your submit button to see if there's a method call. You can also check the Network tab in your browser's developer call to see if you're making an AJAX request when you click on the button.

Comment: Neither the console or the network tab responds. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: You don't see an error message in the browser console either? At this point, if you don't see the server receiving the request and no request sent from your browser's network tab, then your submit button isn't working. Do you have the controller logic?

Comment: It might be because your html is badly formatted. The `form_for` should be before `<div class="modal-body">`

Comment: @mihai - Thanks that was exactly the problem! Didn't notice it in the first place, because a redirect wasn't happening which made me believe that the submit didn't work.

Comment: ok I'll just put it here as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the html is badly formatted. The form_for should be before `<div class="modal-body">`

```
<%= form_for(@item, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit "Wish", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```